# How can i update my experia x10 from 1.6 to 2.1?

Tags: sony-ericsson-xperia-x10

Every time i try to upgrade it through PC companion it stuck in middle when of preparing the phone for installation. I have tried deleting, redownloading and reinstalling the PC companion. But still im not able to update my phone. What should be done?

Comment: Have you tried rebooting the phone?

Answer (score 1):

Call support. They are really helpful. To the Swedish support it's +46-1-324-4500.